# How to use containsObject in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am trying to find if there is any object in the mutable array that matches with the object I pass. Please see the function below.

The name comes from table view controller, so the row that is tapped is saved into name and passed to this function. I am trying to check whether the name in the table view controller equals to the name coming from the database. Here name refers to firstName and lastName..That's the reason I am appending those strings.

Please help me..I am confused of how to do this..if u have any better approach please let me know..thanks a lot..I think its trying to compare the memory locations of the object (not sure though) but is there any way so that it compares exactly the name that I am passing..

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getSearchContacts:(NSString *)name
{
 //---retrieve rows--- 
 NSString *qsql =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM CONTACTS WHERE last_name LIKE '%@",[name substringToIndex:1]]stringByAppendingString:@"%' GROUP BY sugar_id ORDER BY last_name"]; 
 NSString *sugar_id;
 NSString *first_name;
 NSString *last_name;
 NSMutableArray *searchContacts=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 sqlite3_stmt *statement;
 if (searchContactName == nil) {
  searchContactName=[[NSString alloc]init];
 }
 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
  while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) { 
   sugar_id= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
   first_name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
   last_name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];  

   if ([first_name isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {
    last_name=[last_name stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:[[last_name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
    searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:last_name];
    searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:@":"];
    searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:@","];

   }
   else {

    first_name=[first_name stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:[[first_name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
    last_name=[last_name stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:[[last_name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
    searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:last_name];
    searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:@":"];
    searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:first_name];
    searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:@","];

   }
   [searchContacts addObject:searchContactName];
   //first_name = nil;
   //last_name = nil;
    if ([searchContacts containsObject:name]==YES) {
               searchSugarId=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:sugar_id,searchContactName,nil];
   }

  }
  //---deletes the compiled statement from memory--- 
  sqlite3_finalize(statement);
 } 
 return searchSugarId;

}
```

**EDIT**

**Name:** Blackmon:Valentin

**Search Contact Name**
Barefield:Collin,Baylis:Efren,Beatty:Peter,Beckwith:Lynn,Benny:Wilma,Bermudes:Lenore,Berryhill:Gerard,Biles:Jodi,Blackmon:Valentin,Blassingame:Rose,Blume:Renae,Bonet:Claude,Bostic:Valerie,Bouldin:Renaldo,Bracewell:Brendan,Bradford:Kris,Brathwaite:Bill,Brugger:Ismael,Brumit:Julie,Buchholtz:Mathew,Bunker:Chrystal,Burch:Floyd,Burman:Sang,Butcher:Prince,Butcher:Rory,

**searchContacts**
Barefield:Collin,Baylis:Efren,Beatty:Peter,Beckwith:Lynn,Benny:Wilma,Bermudes:Lenore,Berryhill:Gerard,Biles:Jodi,Blackmon:Valentin,Blassingame:Rose,Blume:Renae,Bonet:Claude,Bostic:Valerie,Bouldin:Renaldo,Bracewell:Brendan,Bradford:Kris,Brathwaite:Bill,Brugger:Ismael,Brumit:Julie,Buchholtz:Mathew,Bunker:Chrystal,Burch:Floyd,Burman:Sang,Butcher:Prince,Butcher:Rory,

Comment: Have you tried logging `searchContactName`, `name` and `searchContacts` to check the preceding code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..When I tried to print contents on console..the name I get is correct..please check the values..I edited the above code

Answer (score 3):

`containsObject` will only return a boolean. You maybe want indexOfObject: method.

```
NSInteger index = [array indexForObject:anObject];
```

One thing I noticed in your code is that your are appending too many times a string into the same string. for example why not you use

```
searchContactName = [searchContactName stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:%@,", last_name, first_name];
```

instead of

```
searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:last_name];
    searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:@":"];
    searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:first_name];
    searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:@","];
```

And more important: When doing `searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByDoingSomething]` make sure searchContactName is released otherwise you will be leaking memory.

for example here:

```
searchContactName=[[NSString alloc]init];
...
searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:last_name];
```

you are leaking the first object, then you are just making a new (autoreleased) object by appending `last_name`. If your are initializing like this: `searchContactName=[searchContactName stringByAppendingString:last_name];` then is not necessary to do `[[NSString alloc] init];`

;) hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the reply..I will make the changes suggested by you..they were very helpful..hope I will figure out my problem..

Answer (score 2):

Once you have all your data inside your array (therefore outside of the while), you need to iterate over the array and use the method [isEqualToString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_77) for comparing name with the current array item.

Ok, so have a look at the code below which works:

```
+ (void)testContact {
NSArray *searchContacts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                        @"Barefield:Collin,",
                                                        @"Baylis:Efren,",
                                                        @"Beatty:Peter,",
                                                        @"Beckwith:Lynn,",
                                                        @"Benny:Wilma,",
                                                        @"Bermudes:Lenore,",
                                                        @"Berryhill:Gerard,",
                                                        @"Biles:Jodi,",
                                                        @"Blackmon:Valentin,",
                                                        @"Blassingame:Rose,",
                                                        @"Blume:Renae,",
                                                        @"Bonet:Claude,",
                                                        @"Bostic:Valerie,",
                                                        @"Bouldin:Renaldo,",
                                                        @"Bracewell:Brendan,",
                                                        @"Bradford:Kris,",
                                                        @"Brathwaite:Bill,",
                                                        @"Brugger:Ismael,",
                                                        @"Brumit:Julie,",
                                                        @"Buchholtz:Mathew,",
                                                        @"Bunker:Chrystal,",
                                                        @"Burch:Floyd,",
                                                        @"Burman:Sang,",
                                                        @"Butcher:Prince,",
                                                        @"Butcher:Rory,",nil];
NSString *myContact = @"Blackmon:Valentin,";
for (NSString *contact in searchContacts) {
    if ([contact isEqualToString:myContact]) {
        NSLog(@"FOUND!!!!!");
        break;
    }
}
}
```

If you look carefully, you see that myContact is "Blackmon:Valentin," which has a comma at the end. In your array, all your elements have a comma at the end. But based on what you're showing in your post, the name you're looking for, i.e. **Name:** Blackmon:Valentin doesn't have a comma at the end. Maybe that's why you can't find it. Make sure you add the comma at the end and it should work.

Comment: I tried to iterate over the values in the array but it's not entering the loop even if the values are equal.. I can't understand why :(  This is what I am doing..


for (int i=0; i<[searchContacts count]; i++) 
{
if ([[searchContacts objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:name]) {

searchSugarId=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:sugar_id,name,nil];
   }
  }

Comment: Don't know what to say other than: are you 100% sure the values are equal? As I said above, I tried to code I pasted here in Xcode and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
[mutableArry addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:questionNumber]];
NSLog(@"mutableArry=%@",mutableArry);
  NSLog(@" question not complete  count=%d",mutableArry.count);

if (mutableArry.count==25) {
    NSLog(@"25 question complete%d",mutableArry.count);
}

NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",questionNumber];
NSLog(@"str=%@",str);



 //  array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Nicola", @"Margherita",                                       @"Luciano", @"Silvia", nil];
    if ([mutableArry containsObject:str]) // YES
    {
        NSLog(@"Results");

    }
```

Comment: This is ofc not going to work. You can compare two different object and expect same result.